# Mono-implicit Runge-Kutta-Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I have a question about something from my lecture:

> $"$The mono-implicit Runge-Kutta-Method is given as
>   $$k_i(u_j,u_{j+1})=f((1-\delta_i)u_j+\delta_iu_{j+1}+h\sum_{v=1}^{i-1}a_{iv}k_v(u_j,u_{j+1}))$$
>   $$u_{j+1}=u_j+h\sum_{i=1}^sb_ik_i(u_j,u_{j+1})$$
>   with $\delta_i, a_{iv}, b_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $i=1,...,s$
>
> This equals the regular definition of a Runge-Kutta-Method:
>   $$k_i=f(t+c_ih, u+h\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}a_{ij}k_j)$$
>   $$u_{j+1}=u_j+h\sum_{i=1}^sb_ik_i$$
>   with $b_i, c_i, a_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}"$

My question: How do the methods above equal each other? I've tried to write it down, but I don't see them being similar. Also, something I've been wondering:  What's the point of writing it that way? I don't see any advantages coming from writing it like that.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you sure that the "regular definition" is restricted to only explicit methods? This would contradict the topic of a somewhat implicit method. After that, obviously the coefficients $a_{ij}$ are not the same in both contexts, the second is, expressed in the terms of the first, $a_{ij}+δ_ib_j$ for $j=1,…,s$.